# How to provide highly available, disaster recovery solution for SharePoint 2013 deployment?

Tags: 2013, sql-server, solution-deployment, disaster-recovery

We need to provide highly available, disaster recovery solution for SharePoint 2013 deployment. For this purpose, we've to build environments for two data-centres, one would be primary DC1 and another would be secondary (disaster recovery) DC2 site. In case of any disaster/shut-down, all requests to DC1 would be routed to DC2 by DNS-record update.

Both Primary (DC1) & Secondary DC2 site would have the following environments configuration:

- 2 Web Servers (SharePoint 2013 Web Front End Server running on Windows Server 2008 R2)
- 2 Application Servers (SharePoint 2013 Application Server/Services/Central Admin running 
  on Windows Server 2008 R2)
- 2 Database Servers (Hosting SharePoint 2013 Config/Content DBs on SQL Server 2008/2012)

**Our requirements are as below:**

- We need automatic fail-over between these data-centres, as soon as DC1 is unavailable,  DC2 would be active.
- Do we really need the shared storage like SAN/RAID for SQL Server database in the same data-centre? What would be the criteria for using shared storage?
- Should we use Fail-Over Clustering/ SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn feature for High Availability in the same data-centre  and between data-centres?
- How should we sync these DC1 & DC2 environment i.e. SharePoint and/or SQL Server databases level (Fail-Over Clustering and/or Log Shipping)

Comment: Sounds like a project not an specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hire a capable resource that knows sharepoint...